# Append Map[String, String]() onto an Array or List with [String] type in Scala

Tags: scala

I have stored my key, value pairs in multiple Mutable Map with MapString, String. And I can see the key and values in it. However, now I need to append these maps onto ArrayBuffer or List with String Type in Scala. So that, I can loop over every element in Array and proceed further.
Please help.

Sample Code.

```
val X= scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

  X += ("Name" -> "Raghav")
  X += ("Home" -> "Gurgaon")

val Y= scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

  Y += ("Name" -> "Vikrant")
  Y += ("Home" -> "Noida")

var JobConfigs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

JobConfigs += X
JobConfigs += Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Basically, I want to store Map of key-value pair on each element of ArrayBuffer. I have been able to append the map into ArrayBuffer with following ways -
JobConfigs += X.toString()
JobConfigs += Y.toString()
println(JobConfigs)
ArrayBuffer(Map(Name -> Raghav, Home -> Gurgaon), Map(Name -> Vikrant, Home -> Noida))
Now I need to iterate over each element of ArrayBuffer; then  iterate over Map and print key and values of it.
its throwing issue -
for (e <- JobConfigs) {
      for ((k, v) <- e) {
      println("Key:" + k + ", Value:" + v)
    }
  }

Comment: Will look at basics. So far, working on Python where life is simpler in terms on datatypes.

Comment: If you want, you can share what do you want to do _(all your problem)_and I will provide an answer explaining how you can do that on _idiomatic_ **Scala**. Without that much mutability and using correct types.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> its throwing issue - `for (e <- JobConfigs) { for ((k, v) <- e) { println("Key:" + k + ", Value:" + v) } }`

This doesn't make sense; because your `JobConfigs` is an `ArrayBuffer[String]`, `e` will be a `String` and doesn't contain any pairs. It *will* work, with no other changes, if you change the type of `JobConfigs`:

```
var JobConfigs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Map[String, String]]
```

Alternatively, you could have

```
var JobConfigs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[(String, String)]
JobConfigs ++= X
JobConfigs ++= Y

for ((k, v) <- JobConfigs) { println("Key:" + k + ", Value:" + v) }
```

Side notes:

1. `JobConfigs` should be declared as `val`, unless you later do `JobConfigs = ...`. Even if you do, it's often not a good idea.
2. Idiomatic names for local variables start with a lower-case letter: `x`, `y`, `jobConfigs`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using case classes.

```
case class Person(Name: String, Home: String)

var JobConfig = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Person]()

JobConfig += Person("Raghav", "Gurgaon")
JobConfig += Person("Vikrant", "Noida")

for(i <- JobConfig){
  println(s"home :${i.Home} , name : ${i.Name}")
}

Output: 
home :Gurgaon , name : Raghav
home :Noida , name : Vikrant
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. _"I need to append these maps onto ArrayBuffer or List"_